# How can I fill a vertex with black bars?

Tags: tkz-graph

Suppose I have simple graph drawing like the following.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt, color = black, labelcolor = white]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]

\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {minimum size = 8pt, inner sep = 0pt}}     

\Vertices[unit=2]{circle}{a,b,c,d,e,f}

% It's easy to change the color of a vertex!
\AddVertexColor{white}{a,d} 
\Edges(a,b,c,d,e,f,a)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

From the [documentation](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-graph/doc/tkz-graph-screen.pdf), I could figure out how to change the color of a vertex, as is done in the code. However, I'd like to use *only* black and white to represent several colors. For example, could I have a vertex that is filled with black bars? If so, how? This could represent "blue", while vertex filled with black is "green", and a vertex filled with white is "red".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the `patterns` library, and add `pattern=<style>` to the definition of `VertexStyle`, where `<style>` include, for example, `horizontal lines`, `vertical lines`, `north east lines`, `north west lines`, etc.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt, color = black, labelcolor = white]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]

\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {minimum size = 8pt, inner sep = 0pt, pattern=north east lines}}     

\Vertices[unit=2]{circle}{a,b,c,d,e,f}

% It's easy to change the color of a vertex!
\AddVertexColor{white}{a,d} 
\Edges(a,b,c,d,e,f,a)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]